# Arguments of custom commands as comma separated list?

Tags: macros

Consider the follwing command:

```
 \newcommand{\vektor}[3]{\left(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3    \end{rsmallmatrix}
 \right)}
```

I can use it like

```
$\vektor{1}{2}{3}$
```

Now my question is whether it is possible to redefine the command such that the arguments are a comma separated list, such that I could write:

```
$\vektor{1,2,3}$
```

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15716/3240

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to do this sort of thing using `\def`, if you don't mind putting the argument inside delimiters that are not braces.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\vektor(#1,#2,#3) {\left(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3 \end{smallmatrix} \right)}
\begin{document}
\[ \vektor(a,b,c) \]
\end{document}
```

Obviously, the above would go horribly wrong if you replace the parentheses with braces.

**EDIT**

See Ryan Reich's answer (or Aditya's comment) for a neat modification that allows you to use braces.

Comment: Actually, it is easy to go from this solution to one that uses braces. `\def\vektorwrapper#1{\vektor(#1)}`.

Answer (score 9):

You can do it with `\def` and braces too, if you use two steps to hide Ian Thompson's code inside another macro.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\def\vektor#1{\innervector(#1)}
\def\innervector(#1,#2,#3) {\left(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3 \end{smallmatrix} \right)}
\begin{document}
\[ \vektor{a,b,c} \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: very nice!

Comment: That's cheating!

Answer (score 9):

As an after thought. You can make it a lot more general with a variable number of arguments and different row or column delimiters

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter

\newcommand\myvector[2][\\]{%
    \global\def\my@delim{#1}%
    \left(\negthinspace\begin{smallmatrix}
        \my@vector #2,\relax\noexpand\@eolst%
    \end{smallmatrix}\right)}

\def\my@vector #1,#2\@eolst{%
   \ifx\relax#2\relax
      #1
   \else
      #1\my@delim
      \my@vector #2\@eolst%
   \fi}

\makeatother
\begin{document}
$x   = \myvector{1,2,3,:}$ and
$x^T = \myvector[,&]{1,2,3,...}$
\end{document}
```

This will give

[image]

Comment: ... incidentally, this solution helps me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a solution that uses the `xparse` package:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\InternalVector}{mmm}{%
  \left(\begin{smallmatrix}#1\\#2\\#3\end{smallmatrix}\right)%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\vektor}{>{\SplitArgument{2}{,}}m}{\InternalVector#1}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for smallmatrix

\begingroup\lccode`~=`,
  \lowercase{\endgroup\def\vekcomma{\mathcode`\,=\string"8000 \def~{\\}}}
\newcommand\vektor[1]{\left(\vekcomma
  \!\begin{smallmatrix}
  #1
  \end{smallmatrix}\!\right)}

\begin{document}
$a,b\vektor{a,b,c,d}\vektor{x,y,z}$
\end{document}
```

You are not limited to three components. The `a,b` part is to show that uses of the comma outside the argument of `\vektor` are allowed.

The fact that `\left`-`\right` make a group is fundamental, because this ensures that changes to the `\mathcode` of the comma are confined to that place. The special mathcode `"8000` means that the comma behaves like an active character; the definition of the active comma is given in an indirect way, so as not to conflict with possible other meanings as an active character.