# date interpretation from numbers to regular

Tags: lyx, datetime

I was wondering if there exists such a package, or an option, to write the date in the form 31.1.2012 for example, and then have LaTeX present it as "January 31, 2012". I am actually using LyX and there is an "environment" to put date, However, it puts it in the same manner I am writing it, and for ease of writing I would like to write only numbers.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usdate
\def\mydate#1{\innermydate#1}
\def\innermydate#1.#2.#3{\formatdate{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\begin{document}
\mydate{31.1.2001}
\end{document}
```

The [datetime package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datetime) provides the commands `\usdate` and `\formatdate` (note that `\usdate` redefines `\today`). The macro `\innermydate` sets up the format in which to input dates. You could say `\innermydate1.1.2001` but the syntax with braces is nicer in my opinion, so I borrowed a neat trick from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19698/2417) to facilitate it.

Comment: Thanks. It does work for LaTex, however in LyX it is a problem, since I can't use 'mydate' inside the document (I can write a 'TeX' line inside, but it doesn't output well). Is there a simple solution that will be convenient with LyX?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know. I can only answer the LaTeX part. I hate LyX!