# Typesetting coordinates

Tags: math-mode, typography, vector

I'm trying to typeset coordinates like:

`(0 0 0)` or `(0, 0, 0)`

I'm not sure if LaTeX offers a package which can make the notation a bit more professional than just manually inserting spaces between each coordinate.

Comment: Commas are most frequently used for separating coordinates.

Comment: Related Question: [Typesetting Sets](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/298891/typesetting-sets).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you later decide to change formatting (adjusting spacing, etc.), here's an adaptation of Ryan Reich's answer to a similar question about vectors. It will at least give you a semantic command for coordinates:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% From Ryan Reich, http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19698/3345
\def\vektor#1{\innervector(#1)}
\def\innervector(#1,#2,#3) {\ensuremath{\left( #1,#2,#3 \right)}}

\let\coord\vektor

\begin{document}
Displaymath version, probably not relevant: \[ \coord{a,b,c} \]
Inline version: \coord{a,b,c}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Using `\ensuremath` in this context is very wrong. Try `\coord{a,b,c}=\coord{1,2,3}+\coord{4,5,6}` versus `$\coord{a,b,c}=\coord{1,2,3}+\coord{4,5,6}$`. This is a misuse of concept that easily leeds to bad typography.

Comment: If you mean the change in spacing when your first `\coord` line is rendered as three expressions with text-mode spacing around the `=` and `+`, I agree. If you mean something else, I don't yet understand.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. The macro `\ensuremath` is one of the things I really dislike in LaTeX. IMHO it should have been `\ensur@math` so that unaware users don't use it at all. --- Making math macro available in text mode is very wrong and dangerous, notice that no built-in macros (symbols etc.) don't allow it, nor do the ones you define using standard methods (`\DeclareMathOperator`, `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` etc.). It happens to everybody that he forgets to switch to mathmode and that's why it should raise an error.

Comment: I could be doing it wrong, but in the research proposal I've been writing for far too long, I make tons of use of `\ensuremath` macros. For one, because I've tried to train myself to use `\(` and `\)` instead of '$' and '$', and defining macros so I can more easily write things like `sum of an elastic component (\Jel) and a plastic component (\Jpl)` or `\( \J = \Jel + \Jpl \)` with the two values defined as macros like `\newcommand{\Jel}{\ensuremath{\J_\textnormal{el}}\xspace}` -- is there a better option I've missed somewhere?

Comment: Since I would not put standalone `\Jel`  in parentheses, I would end with `\(\Jel\)`, which is not that bad. And `\xspace` is exactly the second thing I don't like, exactly because it means "losing of control". It's IMHO much more convenient and consistent to write `\xyz{} ` instead of relying on `\xspace` and having to remember whether I put it in the command or not. Of course, in your case, I would have `\(\JpL\) ` and no `{}` not `\xspace`.

Answer (score 15):

A solution that works for any number of coordinates (well, at least one):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\coord}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\left(\coord_print:n {#3}\right)}
   {\mathopen{#2(}\coord_print:n {#3}\mathclose{#2)}}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_coord_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_coord_last_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \coord_print:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_coord_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_coord_list_seq \l_coord_last_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_coord_list_seq { ##1 , }
  \tl_use:N \l_coord_last_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

$\coord{0,1,0}$

$\coord[\Big]{0,1,2,3,4}$

$\coord*{\dfrac{1}{2},2}$

$\coord{1}$

\end{document}
```

With the *-variant we use `\left` and `\right`; with the optional argument one can choose an explicit size (with `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg` or `\Bigg`).

By changing the comma or the parentheses in the definition, one can modify the appearance.

[image]

Comment: You can express that in an easier way using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`, see:
http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/56130/6993

Comment: @mSSM Yes, but with these macros it's easy to change the comma into anything else.

Comment: Shouldn’t you use updated `\left` and `\right` macros (e.g. the ones from `mleftright`) in order to get the right spacing?

Comment: @Gaussler If you so prefer.

Answer (score 9):

You might want to define a dedicated command, like

```
\newcommand{\coord}[3]{\ensuremath{(#1,#2,#3)}}
```

This allows you to insert coordinates in or out of math environments, e.g., `\coord{1}{2}{3}`. Later, you can change the typesetting of the coordinates easily by adapting a single line.

Comment: Using `\ensuremath` in this context is very wrong. Try `\coord{a,b,c}=\coord{1,2,3}+\coord{4,5,6}` versus `$\coord{a,b,c}=\coord{1,2,3}+\coord{4,5,6}$`. This is a misuse of concept that easily leeds to bad typography.

Comment: @tohecz: This depends on the point of view. The problem of your “counter-example” isn't `\ensuremath` for `\coord`, but typesetting a formula containing `+` and `=` outside a math environment.

Comment: Which has never happened to any of us of course. The LaTeX error `Missing $ inserted` (when you use math-mode macro in text-mode) has rescued me many times, and you, by using `\ensuremath` get rid of this rescue system.

Answer (score 5):

You do not have to manually insert any spaces, just use the math-mode and LaTeX will insert the proper spaces itself:

```
We have a vector $(x,y,z)$ that is orthogonal to $(1,2,3)$ and $(4,5,6)$.
```