# Comma delimiter in pmatrix environment (for row vectors)

Tags: amsmath

Is there a way to have a `pmatrix` environment from `amsmath` use non-whitespace delimiters such as a comma? I am mainly asking, because I would like to make a row vector this way. I take it, there are essentially two ways of doing something like that:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    a = \left(1,2,3\right) \\
    b = \begin{pmatrix} 1, & 2, & 3 \end{pmatrix}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

Now, especially the second part does not look too pretty:
[image]

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Typesetting coordinates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53947/typesetting-coordinates)

Comment: Answer is given by: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53961/6993

Comment: That actually reminds me:
An even more elegant solution would be using the following from `mathtools`:
`\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Vector}{\lparen}{\rparen}`.

Comment: Isn't that the same question I linked to?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to point out the actual answer from that link. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53961/6993 provides one solution. It also reminded me of `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\Vector}{\lparen}{\rparen}

\begin{document}
\begin{gather*}
    a = \left(1,2,3\right) \\
    b = \begin{pmatrix} 1, & 2, & 3 \end{pmatrix}
    c = \Vector{1,2,3}
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

A starred version `\Vector*` would precede `\lparen` and `\rparen` by `\left` and `\right`, respectively.

[image]