# Formatting of coordinates?

Tags: formatting, typography, italic, coordinates

In case I want to describe the pixels of a picture with cartesian coordinates, how would I properly typeset the coordinates?
Is `p_\mathrm{x}, p_\mathrm{y}` correct or rather `c_x, c_y`?
`x` and `y` represent the global cartesian coordinates -- again: italic or not?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Related Question: [Typesetting coordinates](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53947/typesetting-coordinates).

Comment: I think this is a matter of style, but I think the `x` and `y` should be italic (as in `$c_x$`) as then the association with `$x$` is clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ll always set them in italic since they are kind of variables. The upright font is used for constant values like Euler’s e etc., functions like the Sine or texts like “min”, “max” which are available as macros (`\min` and `\max`)<sup>*</sup>, “start” or “eff[ective]” In the latter case I recommend to use the `\text` macro from `amsmath` (or via `mathtools`).

<sub>* See Count Zero’s comment</sub>

Some examples

```
p_x = 3.5
p_\text{max} = 4
p_{x,\text{max}} = 5
p_\text{min} = \mathrm{e}
p_0 = \sin(\pi)
t_\text{start} = 2\,\mathrm{s}% better use siuntix!
U_\text{eff} = U_0/\sqrt{2}% I recommend to define \newcommand{\eff}{\text{eff}} to use
u_\eff = U_0/\sqrt{2}
```

[image: examples]

Just a thought: I wonder why you need the `p`? I’d use `$x=1$ and $y=2$` or `$\vec{p}=(1,2)$` if using p as a vector I’d “access” it’s coordinates–like you did–with `p_x` and `p_y`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Programatically this is what I actually do. But I am visualizing my approach and there it is necessary to depict a second coordinate system. My thought was to put 'x' and 'y' upright in the indexes, since they serve more as a comment and less as a variable.

Comment: @PeterPablo: Hm … if they are comments and if this is clearly for the reader I guess it’s possible to set them upright, but I’d prefer the in italic though. In my eyes they are always kinde of variable. I’d even type ` the $xy$ coordinate system` not `the xy coordinate system` …

Comment: I think this is more of a nitpicker's comment, but I'd rather use `\max`, `\min`, etc. in the indices instead of `\text{max}`, `\text{min}`. Typographically it may be the same, but from a markup point of view, I think it's rather different. Hope you don't mind... `:)`

Comment: @CountZero: Thanks. I didn’t know these commands ...