# Typesetting Sets

Tags: math-mode, typography

I adapted a solution from [Typesetting coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53961/4301)
to typeset sets, but it seems to have difficulty with nested usage.

```
$\coord[\big]{0,1, \coord{A,B,C}, \coord{3,2,1}}$
```

yields:

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn  %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53961/4301
\NewDocumentCommand{\coord}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\left(\coord_print:n {#3}\right)}
   {\mathopen{#2\{}\coord_print:n {#3}\mathclose{#2\}}}
 }

\seq_new:N \l_coord_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l_coord_last_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \coord_print:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_coord_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_coord_list_seq \l_coord_last_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_coord_list_seq { ##1 , }
  \tl_use:N \l_coord_last_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    $\coord[\big]{0,1, \coord{A,B,C}, \coord{3,2,1}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Insert `\group_begin:` and `\group_end:` at appropriate places (in my test I added them inside `\coord_print:n`)

Comment: @daleif: Thanks. Replacing `\coord_print:n {#3}` with `{\coord_print:n {#3}}` seems to do he trick. Please post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a case of grouping. Either use

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\coord}{sO{}m}
 {
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\left(\coord_print:n {#3}\right)}
   {\mathopen{#2\{}{\coord_print:n {#3}}\mathclose{#2\}}}
 }
```

note the extra `{}` around `\coord_print:m {#3}`. Or use

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \coord_print:n #1
 {
  \group_start:
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_coord_list_seq { , } { #1 }
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l_coord_list_seq \l_coord_last_tl
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_coord_list_seq { ##1 , }
  \tl_use:N \l_coord_last_tl
  \group_end:
 }
```