# What is the correct way to write a set of multiple variables or the multiples variables of a function in LateX 2e or with standard package?

Tags: math-mode, typography

Which of it is the correct way in English typography, with LaTeX?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$f(x,y)= \ldots$

$f(x,\ y) = \ldots$

$f(x,\,y) = \ldots$

The coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ \ldots

The coordinates $(x,\ y,\ z,\ t)$ \ldots

The coordinates $(x,\,y,\,z,\,t)$ \ldots

The coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ \ldots $\leftarrow$ seems bad.

The coordinates $(x^0,\ x^1,\ x^2,\ x^3)$ \ldots

The coordinates $(x^0,\,x^1,\,x^2,\,x^3)$ \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

I write "seems bad" in the antepenultimate line because I feel same space before and after the commas.

Is there a package that automatize it? E.g a package which provide a command like `\mycoord` which we can use as `\mycoord{x,y,z,t}` and which add the correct spaces between comma in the output?

I'm aware of this question: [Typesetting coordinates](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53947/typesetting-coordinates) but answers are not clear about the spacing between the coordinate, and moreover, I don't want an answer with LaTeX 3, unless it's in a not so recent package (for compatibilities with a bit old system I don't control).

Edit: adding the comparison with a negative space before comma, in the case with variables with exponents.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
1) The coordinates $(x,y,z,t)$ \ldots

2) The coordinates $(x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3)$ \ldots 

3) The coordinates $(x^0\!,x^1\!,x^2\!,x^3)$ \ldots
\end{document}
```

[image]

Does the third seems better than the second?

Second edit:

How I see the spacing (probably wrongly..., but the third seems a little better than the second, but perhaps the negative space is a little too big) :

[image]

Comment: Remove all `\,` bits and “backslash-space”. Now you're done.

Comment: I would not add the thin space, just use the standard comma, so no extra macros are needed

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But doesn't the antepenultimate line be odd in a typographic eye? Seems to be too space before the commas, as the comma is in the middle of the previous and the next object. In contrast, with `$(x,y,z,t)$`, there is more space after the comma than before. Must I keep juste the comma in this case, or add a negative space `\!` before the comma in this specific case?

Comment: @quark67 just let LaTeX do its thing, don't fight it. This is exactly the reason why the comma in math mode has a bigger spacing after it and one have to some something extra to use the comma as a decimal marker.

Comment: no the line marked bad looks _much_ better than the following line.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Please see the edit. Is really the second line better? You have very more experience than me, then if se second line in the second picture is better, then I will leave LaTeX do what he have to do, with simply commas between the variables.

Comment: if the superscripts are large then at most I'd consider pulling the commas back a bit to tuck them under, I wouldn't increase the space after the comma (but I am or was a mathematician not a typographer:-)

Answer (score 5):

The package `semantex` (disclaimer: I am the author) can do many things like this in a customizable way. Unfortunately, it is a relatively recent package, but I believe it should work with older versions of LaTeX3, too, though I have not checked this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,semantex}

\NewVariableClass\MyVar

\NewObject\MyVar\mycoord[
    left par=(,
    right par=),
    set arg sep={,},
    set arg dots=\dotsc,
]

\begin{document}

$ \mycoord{x^0, x^1, ... , x^p} $

\SetupObject\mycoord{
    % Let’s change the settings:
    set arg sep={,\,},
}

$ \mycoord{x^0, x^1, ... , x^p} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Otherwise, for a more portable solution,
you can try editing [this answer by egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53961/19809). As he notes in the comments, the comma can easily be replaced by anything else. And I believe this should work perfectly well with much older versions of LaTeX3.

Comment: Useful package. But I need to find the proper spacing (see my edited question). Perhaps with an adjusted `set arg sep={\!,}` (`\!`seems to be a little to big negative space). Perhaps I'm completely wrong, but my eye is not completely satisfied with the default LaTeX (strange because LaTeX has hight typography default settings).