# Back Reference for Theorems

Tags: macros, hyperref, theorems, back-referencing

Is it possible to create an equivalent of [Backreferences for equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116046/backreferences-for-equations) for theorems, propositions definitions etc.?

Meaning that after stating the theorem it would be stated where the theorem was referenced at and it would work with hyperref.

[Usage of table/figures shown in caption](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14981/usage-of-table-figures-shown-in-caption) provides almost an answer, but how would one append this to happen automatically at the end of an labeled theorem/definition?

Example of what I would need to happen automatically, except with \Cref

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox,xstring,xspace}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%
\let\origref\ref
\renewcommand*\ref[1]{%
  \origref{#1}\xlabel{#1}}
}
\newrobustcmd*\xlabel[1]{%
   \ifcsdef{siteref@doc@#1}{}{\csgdef{siteref@doc@#1}{,}}%
    \@bsphack%
    \begingroup
       \csxdef{siteref@doc@#1}{\csuse{siteref@doc@#1},\thepage}%
         \protected@write\@auxout{}%
        {\string\SiteRef{siteref@#1}{\csuse{siteref@doc@#1}}}%
     \endgroup
     \@esphack%
}

\newrobustcmd*\SiteRef[2]{\csgdef{#1}{#2}}

\newrobustcmd*\xref[1]{%
\ifcsundef{siteref@#1}{%
     \@latex@warning@no@line{Label `#1' not defined}
     }{%
    \begingroup
      \StrGobbleLeft{\csuse{siteref@#1}}{2}[\@tempa]\relax%
      \def\@tempb{}%
      \@tempcnta=0\relax%
      \@tempcntb=\@ne\relax%
      \def\do##1{\advance\@tempcnta\@ne}%
      \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\@tempa}%
       \def\do##1{%
         \ifnum\@tempcntb=\@tempcnta\relax%
            \hyperpage{##1}%
         \else
            \hyperpage{##1},%
          \fi%
          \advance\@tempcntb\@ne
       }%
       [\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\@tempa}]\xspace%
    \endgroup
   }%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}\label{fancytheorem}
Fancy Theorem
\end{theorem}
Referenced on page(s)\xref{fancytheorem}

\newpage\section{page two}\ref{fancytheorem}
\end{document}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you want. I started with your code and added and changed a few things. A no-so-brief summary:

- I renamed `siteref@` as `thmref@` throughout as this made more sense to me:)
- I have wrapped the theorem environment inside a `\NewDocumentEnvironment`, called `Theorem`, that takes two arguments: the optional argument to the `theorem` environment and a (mandatory) label. The label is used to define a `thmref@<label>` macro, which is used to store the page numbers that contain references to the theorem. At the end of the `Theorem` environment the `\xref` command is called in order to automatically add the cross-reference information.
- Rather than writing a `\SiteRef` command to the auxfile every time `\ref` is called I have used `\AtEndDocument` to write it only once using `\SaveTheoremRef`.
- I have made the `\ref` etc smart enough to only save "thmref" information for references associated with theorems. Previously this was stored in the aux file whenever `\ref` was used.
- The code works with `\ref` and `\cref`. I haven't added `\Cref` but that is trivial to do.
- I had to change the `\xref` command as it didn't work for me with multiple references. I also made it print only one page reference for each page and to use `page` or `pages` depending on the number of pages that contain references to the theorem.
- If there are no references, `No references` is printed.

**EDIT**

I have changed the definition of `\@theoremref` so that it now allows references to occur before the theorem. The cost is that `thmref@<label>` references are now constructed for all references, not just theorems, but they are only stored in the aux file for theorems. At the same time I added an "and" between the last two page references when there is more than one reference, which was slightly tricky, and I fixed a bug in the original version of the code by putting the embedded `theorem` environments into their own group. I removed the unnecessary packages and renamed `\xref` as `\AddTheoremReferences` to avoid name conflicts as I think that `\xref` might be defined in some package(?). Finally, as requested in the comments, I allowed for multiple labels being passed to `\ref{...}` and friends.

Here is the output from the first page of my MWE incorporating these changes:

[image]

and here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\makeatletter

% This command is written to the aux file by \SaveTheoremRef, hence
% allowing us to access the cross-referencing data via \thmref@aux@<label>
\newrobustcmd*\TheoremRef[2]{\csgdef{thmref@aux@#1}{#2}}

% save theorem reference data. Called via \AtEndDocument{...}
\newrobustcmd*\SaveTheoremRef[1]{
   \ifcsdef{thmref@#1}{%
     \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\TheoremRef{#1}{\csuse{thmref@#1}}}%
   }{}
}

% stores page reference data in thmref@<label>
\newcommand\@theoremref[1]{%
   \def\do##1{\ifcsdef{thmref@##1}{\csxappto{thmref@##1}{,\number\thepage}}%
                                  {\csxdef{thmref@##1}{\number\thepage}}%
   }%
   \docsvlist{#1}%
}

% Overwrite definitions of \ref and \cref. Since other packages such as
% hyperref and cleverref change these this should be done at the
% beginning of the document.
\AtBeginDocument{
    \let\originalref\ref
    \renewcommand*\ref[1]{\originalref{#1}\@theoremref{#1}}
    \let\originalcref\cref
    \renewcommand*\cref[1]{\originalcref{#1}\@theoremref{#1}}
}

% \AddTheoremReferences<label> prints the cross-referencing information for theorem <label>
\newrobustcmd*\AddTheoremReferences[1]{%
    \ifcsdef{thmref@aux@#1}{% proceed only if thmref data exists
       \def\@tempa{0}% used to check for repeats
       \@tempcnta=0% used to check for plural
       \def\@thmref{}% will contain cross-referencing hyperlinks
       \def\do##1{\ifnum##1=\@tempa\relax% skip over repeat references on each page
                  \else%
                      \ifnum\@tempcnta=1% skip \@tempcnta=0
                        \xappto\@thmref{\noexpand\hyperpage{\@tempa}}% first page reference
                      \else\ifnum\@tempcnta>1% already have ref so add a comma
                           \xappto\@thmref{, \noexpand\hyperpage{\@tempa}}%
                           \fi%
                      \fi%
                      \global\advance\@tempcnta by 1% increment reference counter
                      \edef\@tempa{##1}% store to check for repeat next time
                  \fi%
       }
       \xdef\@@thmref{\csuse{thmref@aux@#1}}
       \expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\@@thmref}
       \typeout{Refefenced: \the\@tempcnta.}
       \ifnum\@tempcnta=1% only one reference
           \noindent[Referenced on page \expandafter\hyperpage{\@tempa}]%
       \else% at least two references so add an "and"
           \noindent[Referenced on pages \@thmref\space and \expandafter\hyperpage{\@tempa}]%
       \fi%
       }{\noindent[Not referenced]\@latex@warning@no@line{Theorem reference `#1' is not defined}}%
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}
% \begin{Theorem}[heading]{label} ... \end{Theorem}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{Theorem}{ o m }
   {\AtEndDocument{\SaveTheoremRef{#2}}
    \IfNoValueTF{#1}{\begin{theorem}}{\begin{theorem}[#1]}
    \label{#2}
   }
   {\end{theorem}\AddTheoremReferences{#2}}


\setcounter{page}{11}% for testing purposes only

\begin{document}
  A reference to \cref{fanciertheorem}.

  \begin{Theorem}{fancytheorem}
  Fancy Theorem
  \end{Theorem}

  \begin{Theorem}[Really fancy!]{fanciertheorem}
  Fancier Theorem
  \end{Theorem}

  \begin{Theorem}[Plain theorem]{plaintheorem}
  Plain Theorem
  \end{Theorem}

  \newpage\section{page two}
    \cref{fancytheorem,fanciertheorem}
    \ref{fanciertheorem}

  \newpage\section{page three}
    \ref{fanciertheorem}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, but there is a problem if the reference is before the theorem, then the references are ignored since it checks the existence of thmref, I tried to override this one but failed so how would one on the first hit write the TheoremRef and pagenumber and after that append pagenumbers to it?

Comment: Well, I think it *did* work because this case did not appear in your MWE! :) This said, I have modified the code to allow for this. See the edit for a description of the changes.

Comment: Another issue is if \cref contains multiple arguments ala \cref{fanciertheorem,fancytheorem}, then we would need to be able to separate the arguments based on comma. I really should have thought my example better. This one [How do I write a macro having comma-separated and variable number of arguments?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15716/how-do-i-write-a-macro-having-comma-separated-and-variable-number-of-arguments) might give the solution.

Comment: @asdfsgt This is a fairly easy enhancement that just requires adding a `\docsvlist` command inside `\@theoremref`. (The macro `\AddTheoremReferences` also processes comma separated variables, or csv lists, using `\docsvlist`.) Done!

Comment: Thanks! This worked almost perfectly, but I found some weird behavior still: If the page number is twice the same number f.e. 11 or 22, then the commands \@@thmref and \@tempa does not seem to work because of the line 
\ifx##1@\relax% ignore the leading @
but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Comment: The problem was caused by the line `\ifx##1@\relax` and, in fact, this was failing whenever the page number was greater than 9. I have made the code more efficient by removing the  `@`'s from the lists of references (this was a sleight-of-hand to avoid worrying about adding a comma that became unnecessary when I allowed the new `\cref` and friends to accept multiple references). The output is the same except that now it works! I have changed the page number to 11 in the MWE to show this.