# List all theorems where some theorem is used

Tags: hyperref, back-referencing

I would like to have the following feature: Imagine I have a text like this.

Theorem 1: Every integer has a successor.

Theorem 2: There are infinitely many integers.

Proof: We use Theorem 1 here.

What I want to achieve is a little note on the margin near Theorem 1 indicating (with a hyperlink) that Theorem 2 (or its proof) uses Theorem 1.

How does this work? (It is similar to backref, but I want to apply it to theorem-like environments and I want to get not just the page number where the theorem is used, but the precise environment itself.)

Comment: Did you have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349204/back-reference-for-theorems ?