# Macro for a sequence of variables

Tags: macros

Currently, I have a macro `\bigseq` which takes a variable name and a last number and produces `#1_{1},#1_{2},\ldots,#1_{#2}`, and for example `x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}`.

Now, sometimes I want to produce a full sequence when given specific numbers. I would like a macro `\seq` that takes a first and last index and outputs the entire sequence. For example, for `3` and `7`, I want to get `x_{3},x_{4},x_{5},x_{6},x_{7}`. Is that possible?

Comment: See [Writing a macro to typeset a variable number of terms of a series](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14719/2975). It is slightly different but the solution should work for you as well with minor modifications.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand{\bigseqx}[3]{{#1_{#2}%
  \count255=\numexpr#2\relax
  \whileboolexpr{ test {\ifnumcomp{\count255}{<}{\numexpr#3\relax}}}
    {\advance\count255 by 1 ,#1_{\number\count255 }}%
}}

\begin{document}
$\bigseqx{x}{3}{7}$
\end{document}
```

Some explanations. We use the `\whileboolexpr` macro of etoolbox (there are other packages that offer similar functionality); it takes two arguments: the first one is a test introduced by the `test` keyword, followed by the actual test, so we'll execute the code in the second argument as long as the test evaluates as true. But before starting this loop, we typeset the first element of the sequence and set a temporary counter to the second argument to `\bigseqx` (the first one is the symbol for the variable). The code increments the counter and typesets a comma and the next subscripted variable. The test evaluates as false when the counter becomes equal to the third argument.

We set the temporary counter to a value computed by `\numexpr` and use again `\numexpr` for comparing the counter to the third argument, so input such as

```
\bigseqx{x}{\value{cnt}}{\value{cnt}+9}
```

(where `cnt` is a LaTeX counter) is valid; `\numexpr\value{cnt}+9\relax` evaluates the expression (and the `\relax` token is swallowed because it's simply a terminator for the numeric expression).

---

<sub>Note: at the moment I wrote the answer I wasn't using `expl3`.</sub>

It's even shorter with `expl3`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\bigseqx}{mmm}
 {
  #1\sb{#2}
  \int_step_inline:nnnn { #2+1 } { 1 } { #3 }
   {
    , #1\sb{##1}
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

$\bigseqx{x}{3}{7}$

\end{document}
```

The idea is the same as above, but the working should be clearer: we print the first element, then a comma and the next element until we're finished. The key point is `\int_step_inline:nnnn` that takes as arguments the starting point, the step, the final point and the action to perform, in which we can refer to the current value by `#1` (it's `##1` because `\int_step_inline:nnnn` is used in a definition). Each of the first three arguments can be an integer expression using any of the math facilities of `expl3`.

Comment: This is hardly understandable, plus it won't run with my texlive here, should I say the code is wrong ?

Comment: @Eeva --- you should not say that egreg's code is wrong, because it is not. @egreg --- perhaps you could add a sentence or two explaining the purpose of the two `\relax` commands here.

Comment: @Eeva, check if you have a recent installation, perhaps?

Comment: @Bruno Le Floch, will do, sorry about the previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

Here the adjusted form of my answer to [Writing a macro to typeset a variable number of terms of a series](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14719/writing-a-macro-to-typeset-a-variable-number-of-terms-of-a-series/14721#14721), which now allows for a user-defined minimal index. It is fully expandable, except of the robust `\ensuremath` which can be removed if required..
Use it like `\seq{<var>}{<min>}{<max>}`, e.g. `\seq{x}{3}{7}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand*{\seq}[3]{% #1 = variable, #2/#3 = min./max. number of terms
    \ensuremath{%
    \ifnum#2<0 \else
        #1_{#2}\expandafter\seqx\expandafter{\the\numexpr#2+1\relax}{#3}{#1}%
    \fi
    }%
}

% Internal recursive macro
\newcommand*{\seqx}[4]{% #1 = current index, #2 = max index, #3 = variable, #4 = \fi
    #4% = \fi
    \ifnum#1>#2 \else
        +#3_{#1}%
        \expandafter\seqx\expandafter{\the\numexpr#1+1\relax}{#2}{#3}%
    \fi
}

\begin{document}

\seq{x}{1}{10}

\seq{x}{3}{7}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that `#4=\fi` is very nice. I wouldn't use braces around `#1` in `\seq` and `#3` in \seqx, as this won't give correct results for `\seq{x'}{1}{8}`. And, of course, I wouldn't use `\ensuremath`. :-)

Comment: @egreg: You are right about the braces, but why not use `\ensuremath`?

Comment: @egreg: Ok, I just figured that `\ensuremath` is robust and will add some extra stuff in an `\edef` context to the otherwise fully expandable macro. But that feature isn't that important anyway in this application.

Comment: my opinion is that math should be confined in math environments. It's very rare that a command benefits from `\ensuremath`. But that's just an opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could also do that with the \forloop package, below is a small example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{forloop}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{themenumber}
\newcommand{\seq}[2]
{%
\forloop{themenumber}{#1}{\value{themenumber} < #2}{%
    $ x_{\arabic{themenumber}}, $%
}%
}

\seq{2}{6}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, the end number needs to be fixed, and a test is to be added to remove the last coma. Sorry for that, but the main idea is here

Comment: The code is wrong in many aspects. You are wasting a counter for each call of `\seq`, for example. And there's a trailing comma, with wrong spacing after inner commas.

Comment: You're right, I moved the counter out of the newcommand.

Comment: @egreg: I find it readable, and the point is made.